# Mustache & Sinatra - is it possible to omit the view.rb file?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mustache

I'm using the Mustache templating library with Sinatra and the standard way seems to be to create, say, index.mustache under /templates and an associated index.rb that subclasses `Mustache` in /views.

For things like the About page, where no special logic happens at all, how is it possible to use *only* a .mustache template and still do the following in Sinatra:

```
get "/" do
  mustache :about
end
```

When I simply don't provide the index.rb file, Mustache throws an error about not being able to find it.

Comment: Not sure about mustache but with haml you can do `Haml::Engine.new("%p foo").render` to render inline, there's probably a similar method with mustache

Comment: Doh, I misread your question, thought you were looking to render with no template whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is very simple. If you don't have a view model (like index.rb) you just use another template system like erb

```
erb :about
```

or if the file is static just put it here

```
./public/about.html
```

I doesn't make sense to hava .mustache template without a view model.

Answer (score 0):

That view requirement is annoying. Jason Campbell comes to the rescue with https://github.com/jxson/sinatra-mustache